# Use --strip when extracting multiple tarballs?

Tags: bash, macos

I have  1000s of tarballs containing a couple of files each in a directory I don't need.

Whilst this works fine:

`tar -xvzf ev-10-0003.tgz --strip=1`

This causes errors:

`tar -xvzf *.tgz --strip=1`

Comment: Could you provide the exact error, please?

Comment: tar: --strip=1: Not found in archive
...

Comment: Try to pass the option before your glob: `tar -xvzf --strip=1 *.tgz`

Comment: Tar tries to treat --strip=1 as the tarball and fails: tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '--strip=1'

Comment: Sorry, my fault :/ `tar --strip=1 -xvzf *.tgz` should work

Comment: Which version of OS X are you using? In mine, the option `strip` is not documented in `man tar`. The one that comes closest is: `--strip-components`.

Comment: That doesn't work either I'm afraid.  OSX is 10.12.6 but --strip is not in the man pages.

Comment: If it's not in the man page, are you sure that it's even there? Might it just be ignored in the first command? It looks like `--strip-components` is there, according to the online [man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tar.1.html).

Comment: Use stripping as documented then: `tar --strip-components 1 -xvzf *.tgz`

Comment: strip-components doesn't work